# numerical differentiation of data

Tags: r

I have a data set correponding to observations of a real valued function of two variables, that is (z,x,y), where z=f(x,y).
I need to compute the cross derivative of f at the available data points, that is df/dxdy.
The function gradient from the pracma package offers a solution for this question but only when the observed points (x,y) come from a regular grid. 
Is there any code available to do that ?

Best regards

Comment: You need to post some data if you want an answer.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: try the `numDeriv` package?

Comment: @BenBolker, or in other words, `upper.tri(numDeriv::hessian(z, c(x,y)))`

Comment: `upper.tri()` might not work the way you think it does though ...

Comment: ah good point. a variation on that then.

Comment: numDeriv::hessian needs a function as a first argument (z); it can't handle a vector corresponding to thr function values...

Comment: @user2554330 a simple example from the gradient help page   x <- seq(0, 1, by=0.2)
     y <- c(1, 2, 3)
     (M <- meshgrid(x, y))
   z = M$X^2 + M$Y^2
     gradient(z, x, y)
     Here x and y are vectors of grid points for both dimensions, and z=f(x,y)= x²+y².